# Attribute Error while running load module in Geodjango

Tags: django, geodjango

I am following this documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/

And i did layerMapping and run the load module by

```
from world import load
load.run()
```

And my load.py is

```
__author__ = 'arun'
import os
from django.contrib.gis.utils import LayerMapping
from world.models import WorldBorder

world_mapping = {
 'fips' : 'FIPS',
 'iso2' : 'ISO2',
 'iso3' : 'ISO3',
 'un' : 'UN',
 'name' : 'NAME',
 'area' : 'AREA',
 'pop2005' : 'POP2005',
 'region' : 'REGION',
 'subregion' : 'SUBREGION',
 'lon' : 'LON',
 'lat' : 'LAT',
 'mpoly' : 'MULTIPOLYGON',
```

}

```
 world_shp = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'E:\Django\geodjango\world\data\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp'))

def run(verbose=True):
  lm = LayerMapping(WorldBorder, world_shp, world_mapping,
                  transform=False, encoding='iso-8859-1')

  lm.save(strict=True, verbose=verbose)
```

After  from world import load
       load.run()

Am getting an error as attached below. Help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using one of the [spatial backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#module-django.contrib.gis.db.backends) in your `DATABASES` settings.

- django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis
- django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql
- django.contrib.gis.db.backends.oracle
- django.contrib.gis.db.backends.spatialite